# how to write Nginx config file of two node.js apps in one server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

I have a server where a node.js app is running
Now I want to run another app on the same server
I don't know what changes I should make to my nginx file

Please guide me

this is my nginx file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name beranggrup.com , www.beranggrup.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP                 $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host                      $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-NginX-Proxy         true;
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:3445;
        proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
  location /images/ {
       alias /opt/public/images/;
  }

}
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name beranggrup.com;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and  read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do you want your another app to be running ?
in the same path **beranggrup.com** with extended url like **/another** or
different path like **anotherapp.com** ?
Please provide these info of how your both of the applications be running and rendering so that the question be still more clear.